# MongoDB - how to join parent and child products by reference

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

my mongo collection stores products. There are two product types: child and parent. Parent product holds array of its child as reference.

Use case:

```
use mydb;

child1 = {
    _id: 1,
    name: "Child 1",
    is_child: true,
    is_parent: false,
    children : []
}

child2 = {
    _id: 2,
    name: "Child 2",
    is_child: true,
    is_parent: false,
    children : []
}

parent = {
    _id: 3,
    name: "Parent product",
    is_child: false,
    is_parent: true,
    children : [1, 2]
}

db.product.insert( [child1, child2, parent] );
```

And I'm looking for any query returning

```
{
    _id: 3,
    name: "Parent product",
    is_child: false,
    is_parent: true,
    children: [
        {
            _id: 1,
            name: "Child 1",
            is_child: true,
            is_parent: false,
            children : []
        },
        {
            _id: 2,
            name: "Child 2",
            is_child: true,
            is_parent: false,
            children : []
        }
    ] 
}
```

I'm newbie to mongodb, but I guess an usage of map-reduce could solve the problem. Can anyone advice? Thx

Comment: You could do this on software level using two roundtrips. Drivers like Mongoose (http://mongoosejs.com/) offer this out of the box. So called "populating".

Comment: Is there any way how to do it by query?

Comment: If you ask about single `find` or `findOne` command the answer is no.

Comment: MongoDB doesn't have joins. There are no "workarounds" to make joins work anymore. You need to layout your schema differently, or accept that the data will be retrieved in multiple steps. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/data-models-relationships/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From shell you can use code like below, although it is not very effective approach. Depending on the size of children documents and the level of nesting you should consider embedding instead of linking.

```
query = {_id: 3}
db.product.find(query).map(function(doc) {
    doc.children = db.product.find({_id: {$in: doc.children}}).toArray();
    return doc;
})
```

Comment: May be it could solve my problem, at least it returns in shell what I want, but is cursor.map() supported by any PHP client lib? I'm not able to find it

Comment: Is there any other language binding supporting cursor.map() ?

Comment: There is nothing special in `map`. It just takes iterable object, applies some function to each element and returns an array of modified elements. You can mimic that behavior in any client using for example loops.